# Условие IF в триггере

Tags: mysql, триггер

Я вставляю данные в таблицу:

```
LOCK TABLES `import_files_log` WRITE;

INSERT  INTO `import_files_log`(`id`,`import_files_id`,`inserted_ok`,`inserted_error`,`file`,`common_error_cause`,`import_start_date`,`import_finish_date`) VALUES (1,2,230,0,'D:\\Test\\file.txt',NULL,'2010-10-28 11:39:13','2010-10-28 11:39:13'),

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

и получаю следующую ошибку:

> Error Code: 1100
>
> Table 'data_files' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

При этом связь с таблицей `data_files` находится в триггере:

```
CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'%' */
    TRIGGER `import_files_log_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `import_files_log` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF (NEW.import_files_id=599999997 AND new.file LIKE '%SR3%.700' AND new.inserted_ok>0) THEN
     
          -- тут происходит вставка данных в таблицу data_files

END IF; 
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

И что мне непонятно, так это то, что условие в триггере не выполняется, почему тогда таблица `data_files` должна быть залочена?

**P.S.** В том, условие в триггере не выполняется, я убедилась. Например, после удаления триггера, вставки данных в таблицу `import_files_log` и выполнения запроса:

```
SELECT *
FROM `import_files_log`
WHERE `import_files_id`=599999997 AND `file` LIKE '%SR3%.700' AND `inserted_ok`>0;
```

я не получила никаких данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из документации MySQL

> If you lock a table explicitly with LOCK TABLES, any tables used in triggers are also locked implicitly, as described in Section 14.3.5.2, “LOCK TABLES and Triggers”.

Что в переводе означает примерно следующее

> Если вы явно блокируете таблицу вызовом LOCK TABLES, то любые таблицы, в которым идет обращение из триггеров также неявно блокируются, как описано в разделе 14.3.5.2, “LOCK TABLES and Triggers”.

Comment: Было бы неплохо если бы вы продублировали это на русском. Всё-таки не все знают английский хорошо и уверенно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский программист, который не может читать английскую документацию - это нонсенс

Comment: Программисты это люди. А люди не рождаются сразу с навыками читать по-английски. Даже сами носители этого языка. Они обучаются в процессе. И да, на начальном этапе возможны перебои со знанием английского также, как и знанием основ программирования, в принципе, что логично.