# Mysql, ошибка 1442

Tags: mysql

При вставке в таблицу `terminals` данных:

```
LOCK TABLES `terminals` WRITE;

insert  into `terminals`(...) values (...); 

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

получаю следующую ошибку:

> Error Code: 1442
>
> Can't update table 'terminals_pools' in
>   stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which
>   invoked this stored function/trigger.

Подозреваю, что данная ошибка происходит из-за того, что в этой базе данных существует триггер:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `my_db`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `insert_terminals`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'user'@'%' */
    TRIGGER `insert_terminals` AFTER INSERT ON `terminals` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   UPDATE my_db.`terminals_pools` SET  last_resize_date = NOW() WHERE id= NEW.terminals_pools_id;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Но почему происходит эта ошибка? Ведь обновление строк должно происходить последовательно, т.е. вставка строки -> вызов и выполнение триггера -> вставка следующей строки -> вызов и выполнение триггера, или я не права?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [документации](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables-and-triggers.html) сказано

> If you lock a table explicitly with LOCK TABLES, any tables used in triggers are also locked implicitly, as described in Section 14.3.5.2, “LOCK TABLES and Triggers”.

Что в переводе означает примерно следующее

> Если вы явно блокируете таблицу вызовом LOCK TABLES, то любые таблицы, в которым идет обращение из триггеров также неявно блокируются, как описано в разделе 14.3.5.2, “LOCK TABLES and Triggers”.

Т.е. вам нужно вызывать

```
LOCK TABLES `terminals` WRITE, `terminals_pools`;
```

А вообще это [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574154/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-if-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5) Вашего же вопроса

Comment: Там была другая ошибка - 1100, но вообще да, вы правы, ошибки разные, а причина одна.